# Derived table VS Subquery in SQL Server: pros and cons

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning SQL Server and and interested in knowing what circumstances dictate the use of each concept.  I have simple example below that would return the same data.  My questions is, in real-life examples, how does one decided which technique to use?

```
select empName
, empTitle
, empID
from (select empName, empTitle, empID from tblManagers) as mgrs
```

versus:

```
select empName
, empTitle
, empID
from tblEmployees
where empID in (select empID from tblManagers)
```

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a better example? From your sample there, I don't understand why you'd use either instead of just `select empName, empTitle, empID from tblManagers` and nothing else

Comment: @dman2306 I bet this is just an example code to show people who are not familiar with concepts what it actually is. I assume that author would like to know the theory behind picking one method over another.

Comment: @dman2306  

ConsiderMe is right:  I was asking about the underlying theory here.

Answer (score 1):

Sql server is smart enought, so first statement:

```
select empName
, empTitle
, empID
from (select empName, empTitle, empID from tblManagers) as mgrs
```

is converted to:

```
select empName
, empTitle
, empID
from tblManagers
```

There is one table scan. The second statement produces 2 table scans and then does nested loops for in operator. So the first statement is a winner hear.

As a recommendation you should always check on data. You should check execution plans. Shorter and good looking statement is not always the best. One and the same statement could give you different results on different data etc etc. It depends on many things.

You can see three statement along with their execution plans here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f53f/3

Answer (score 0):

Your two queries do different things, so I cannot comment on them.

In SQL Server, this is about three things -- none of which are performance related:

- Do you have to use a CTE because you are using a recursive CTE?
- Are you using the query-logic multiple times in the code?
- Do you have a preference for one or the other?

SQL Server treats non-recursive CTEs and subqueries exactly the same way from a performance perspective.  They both get inserted into the execution plan as "raw SQL".  That is, there is no separate compilation or materialization of either one.  As far as I know, there still isn't even a compiler hint for materialization.

CTEs generally have some advantages.  You can refer to them multiple times in the same query, providing an opportunity to re-use code.  For instance, I often have a structure where I define "constant" parameters for queries as:

```
with params as (select 'x' as val1)
```

Then I can `cross join` that into any subquery that I need, and the parameter only need to be changed once.

CTEs can refer to each other without nesting.  This helps simplify the look of queries.

CTEs support recursion.

That said, I often use both.